Qt app crashes when app is built with NDK toolchain on Android
What I started with and what brought me success:

I have simple c++ app:

main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


CmakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(HELLO_WORLD)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(HELLO_WORLD main.cpp)


I have NDK 20.0.5594570

and I use the toolchain to cross-compile a linux application for the arm64-v8a architecture, that is, in fact, for Android. To do this, I used the following cmake call:
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug 
"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2024.1.1/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" 
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake 
-G Ninja 
-S C:\Users\user\CLionProjects\HELLO_WORLD
-B C:\Users\user\CLionProjects\HELLO_WORLD\cmake-build-debug


After building the app i got executable, which i pushed to my phone (Sumsung A73) in /data/HELLO_WORLD_DIR
What did I do next:
a73xq:/data/HELLO_WORLD_DIR # chmod +x HELLO_WORLD                                                                                                                                                                                 
a73xq:/data/HELLO_WORLD_DIR # ./HELLO_WORLD                                                                                                                                                                                        
Hello, World!
a73xq:/data/HELLO_WORLD_DIR #

It works! Goodbye!
The problems started when I needed to use QT. Now I have a:

Qt 5.15.2 for android

It contains Qt libraries for various ABIs (all compiled using NDK 20.0.5594570)

I add -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a" in cmake call and ran into problem: libraries "log", "z" and "c++_shared" were required (for last i added -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared in cmake call)

For resolve it i change CmakeLists.txt to:


    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
    project(QHELLO_WORLD)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

    set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/5.15.2/android")
    set(Qt5_DIR "C:/Qt/5.15.2/android/lib/cmake/Qt5")
    set(Qt5Core_DIR "C:/Qt/5.15.2/android/lib/cmake/Qt5Core")

    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS
            Core
            REQUIRED)

    add_executable(QHELLO_WORLD main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(QHELLO_WORLD
            Qt5::Core
            log
            z
    )

I didn't copy the libraries to the build directory because I still need to deploy everything manually.

After successful building i pushed my executable and libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so to /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR on my phone. But at startup, an error about the absence appeared of libc++_shared.so.
Then I found this library in my NDK folder (C:\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so) and also push in my phone. That's what happened next:
a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # file QHELLO_WORLD ; file libc++_shared.so ; file libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so
QHELLO_WORLD: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, dynamic (/system/bin/linker64), for Android 21, built by NDK r20 (5594570), BuildID=b55348816298fb62b2b1f1accc8d5f835d208402, not stripped
libc++_shared.so: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, BuildID=a9c0aad7747976d255d9ea273f6f4c5003901317, for Android 21, built by NDK r20 (5594570), not stripped
libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, BuildID=44558e4e8df807aa073661c0b1fc210761f81ed2, for Android 21, built by NDK r20 (5594570), not stripped
a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH                                                                                                                                      
a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # ./QHELLO_WORLD
Segmentation fault 
139|a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # 

I have SEGFAULT and i dont know what is it
tombstone the app:
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a73xqxx/a73xq:12/SP1A.210812.016/A736BXXU2AVG3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '8'
ABI: 'arm64'
Processor: '6'
Timestamp: 2024-08-29 16:20:28.200691909+0300
Process uptime: 0s
Cmdline: ./QHELLO_WORLD
pid: 25810, tid: 25810, name: QHELLO_WORLD  >>> ./QHELLO_WORLD <<<
uid: 0
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000030  x3  0000000000000010
    x4  0200007b3189d540  x5  b400007b3189d41d  x6  000000002d465455  x7  00000000382d4654
    x8  0000007d253de000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 000000003189d538
    x12 0000ffff00000eff  x13 00000000f0d2df74  x14 00000000fffffff4  x15 0000007d25138040
    x16 0000007d253b9298  x17 0000007d2506fb18  x18 0000007d28d16000  x19 0000007ff2e55b90
    x20 0000007d28b2d010  x21 0000007d28b2d010  x22 0000007ff2e55e38  x23 0000007ff2e55db4
    x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000007d28b2d010  x27 0000000000000000
    x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007ff2e55b80
    lr  0000007d25074568  sp  0000007ff2e55b40  pc  0000007d25074568  pst 0000000060001000

backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000232568  /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so (QJNIEnvironmentPrivate::QJNIEnvironmentPrivate()+36) (BuildId: 44558e4e8df807aa073661c0b1fc210761f81ed2)
      #01 pc 0000000000232e74  /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so (QJNIObjectData::~QJNIObjectData()+36) (BuildId: 44558e4e8df807aa073661c0b1fc210761f81ed2)
      #02 pc 00000000002399e8  /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so (QtSharedPointer::CustomDeleter<QJNIObjectData, QtSharedPointer::NormalDeleter>::execute()+24) (BuildId: 44558e4e8df807aa073661c0b1fc210761f81ed2)

I also tried to check the dependencies:
127|a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # ldd /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/QHELLO_WORLD                                                                                                                                                         
        linux-vdso.so.1 => [vdso] (0x7a8a8ad000)
        libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so => /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so (0x7a8383c000)
        liblog.so => /system/lib64/liblog.so (0x7a89308000)
        libz.so => /system/lib64/libz.so (0x7a89424000)
        libm.so => /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libm.so (0x7a89447000)
        libc++_shared.so => /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libc++_shared.so (0x7a86684000)
        libdl.so => /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libdl.so (0x7a892eb000)
        libc.so => /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (0x7a8678f000)
        libc++.so => /system/lib64/libc++.so (0x7a89344000)
a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # ldd /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so                                                                                                                                                  
Could not find a PHDR: broken executable?
Aborted 
134|a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # ldd /data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR/libc++_shared.so                                                                                                                                                     
Could not find a PHDR: broken executable?
Aborted

1|a73xq:/data/QHELLO_WORLD_DIR # readelf -d  libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so                                                                                                                                                               

Dynamic section at offset 0x564fc0 contains 35 entries:
  Tag                Type                 Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++_shared.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libQt5Core_arm64-v8a.so]
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x567c20
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x567c30
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       32 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x260
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0xac90
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x3eff8
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x17350
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              257525 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x5751f0
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           50568 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x9f150
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x81360
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             122352 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x81300
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         3
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x7ddee
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          2008
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

I really don't understand very well how to set up dependencies on system libraries, and what does JNI have to do with it

The problem is the same on Qt6:
backtrace:       #00 pc 00000000004a3c88  /data/Q6HELLO_WORLD_DIR/libQt6Core_arm64-v8a.so (QJniEnvironment::QJniEnvironment()+56) (BuildId: 0af00b59c80b03d6116a9f8c7575d1b21efc7d89) ...

I don't think console mode is supported by Qt for Android. Did you try to make a GUI app? I'd recommend using Qt Quick. Also, I would not recommend to use Qt 5.12 for Android - it's too old.

I'm trying to create a purely console application, besides, it should be in ELF format, not APK, so I have to squirm

Okay, that's impossible :)
